# sql average function in access

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the average wholesale cost by vendor. I have to create a computed field as avg wholesale and include the vendor code field in the result. I've been trying to figure this one out and I did research but can't get it to work everytime it says missing operator. How is this done?

Comment: Help us help you - please share your table's structure, the query you've tried using and the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Vendor, AVG(WholesaleCostVariableName)
  FROM TableName
 GROUP BY Vendor
```

Comment: My table is called item and I have wholesale cost and vendor code as fields I have to find the average wholesale cost and compute a new field called avg wholesale and include vendor code in the result.

Comment: This is not a spoonfeeding site.  This answer puts you on the right track.  You have to take it from here.